# Is mgo bson marshalling guaranteed to preserve order of struct components?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I am saving go structs in mongo using mgo. I wish to save them with a hash of that struct (and a secret) to determine whether they have been tampered with (and I do not wish the mongo db itself to have the secret).

Currently I am hashing the structs by serializing them using `gob` whose ordering of struct components is well-defined. This works great, save when I go to reread the struct from mango, things have changed - to be precise the time values in mongo have truncated accuracy compared to go - therefore the hashes do not match up.

My planned work around for this is simply to marshall and unmarshall the struct from BSON before calculating the hash, i.e.:

- Marshal struct to BSON
- Unmarshal struct from BSON (thereby losing precision on time)
- Marshall struct to gob and hash resultant `[]byte`
- Put hash in struct
- Save struct to mongo

Now, that's more than a little circuitous.

If I could guaranteed that the BSON itself always preserved order of components in structs, I could:

- Marshal struct to BSON
- hash resultant `byte[]`
- Put hash in struct
- Save struct to mongo

Which would be less nasty (albeit that it would still require converting to BSON twice).

Any ideas?

Comment: @BravadaZadada well if not that would be another reason to use BSON (one presumes it's true there or searches would be hard)

Comment: @BravadaZadada done - https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your actual question, yes, you can trust `mgo/bson` to always marshal struct fields in the order they are observed in the code. Although not yet documented ([issue](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/132)), this is very much intentional behavior, and even mgo itself depends on it internally.

Now, responding to your intended usage: *don't do that.* The fact fields are in a guaranteed order does not mean the binary format is stable as a whole. Even now there are known ways the output can change without breaking even the existing clients, but that would break a hash of its output.

Here is some suggested reading to understand a bit better the ins and outs of the problem you are trying to solve (I'm the author):

- http://blog.labix.org/2013/06/25/strepr-v1
- http://blog.labix.org/2013/07/03/reference-strepr-implementation

This is precisely addressing the issue of marshaling an arbitrary or map with arbitrary fields and keys in a stable way, to obtain a stable hash out of it for signatures. The reference implementation is in Go.

Comment: Thanks - that is my problem exactly. Currently I'm serialising manually by iterating through the fields in definition order with the `structs` package. I note your spec doesn't currently include unambiguous ways of serializing time, which is something to think about (`go` and `gob` hold time to a greater precision than `bson`).

Answer (score 0):

BSON keeps order. I would do all secret in a couple of simple wrap function:

```
type StructWrap struct{
    Value bson.Raw
    Hash []byte
}

func save2mgo(in interface{}){
    str := StructWrap{}
    orig,_err := bson.Marshal(in)
    str.Value = bson.Raw{0, orig}
    str.Hash = <do hash based on orig bytes>
    //to save str to mgo. because Value already in bson.Raw, it will not do marshal again.
}

func unmarshal(inType interface{}){
    //read from mgo
    //check str.Hash here 
    str.Value.Unmarshal(inType)
}
```

hope can help you.

Comment: How do you BSON is guaranteed to keep order?

Comment: I not want to say more about BSON. The really problem is not to marshal twice, and my solution works for it.